# Can Clojure's protocol functions be variadic like ordinary functions?

Tags: clojure, protocols

With clojure functions, I can define:

```
(defn f [x & xs] (apply some-function x xs))
```

I'm attempting to do this same sort of thing with a protocol, e.g.

```
(defprotocol foo
  (bar [f])
  (baz [f & gs]))
```

This compiles (at least in the REPL), but any implementing type seems to fail on this (the variadic, baz) method.  Is this officially not supported?  The sources that I've consulted are silent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not supported, for the reasons Stuart Sierra gives. To go into a little more detail, the `&` symbol is special only in a destructuring context like `let` or function arguments. As Stuart makes clear, `defprotocol` is not such a context.

But `&` is still a legal symbol, so you've defined a protocol with two functions: `bar` takes one argument, named `f`, and `baz` takes three, named `f`, `&`, and `gs`.

Comment: FYI, there is a jira issue to flag the use of & in this context as an error. http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-888

Answer (score 10):

As answered Stuart Sierra in [following thread](https://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/0077f2cd70a0bd39?fwc=1), variadic methods aren't supported, and possibly will not supported in the future