# What's wrong with this use of rest params with defprotocol and defrecord in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, variadic-functions

What's wrong with the below use of rest params with defprotocol and defrecord in Clojure?

```
(defprotocol prot
  (f [this] [this & rest]))

(defrecord rec []
  prot
  (f [this] "one arg")
  (f [this & rest] "more than one arg"))

(prn (f (rec.)))
; (prn (f (rec.) 5))
(prn (f (rec.) 5 6))
; (prn (f (rec.) 5 6 7))
```

The above code prints the output I expect:

```
"one arg"
"more than one arg"
```

But if I uncomment either of the commented lines, I get the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No single method: f of interface: user.prot found for function: f of protocol: prot (bug.clj:10)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:5376)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:5190)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:5151)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3057)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:5371)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:5190)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:5151)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:4670)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:4328)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3173)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:5367)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:5190)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5421)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:5857)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:340)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:327)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:319)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:220)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:273)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:354)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:409)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:365)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No single method: f of interface: user.prot found for function: f of protocol: prot
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.<init>(Compiler.java:2880)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3063)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:5371)
    ... 24 more
```

Why is this?

Comment: It seems that protocols dispatch function doesn't support functions with variadic params.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do clojure protocols allow one to have a variadic method the way funcions do (with an ampersand)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401378/do-clojure-protocols-allow-one-to-have-a-variadic-method-the-way-funcions-do-wi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, protocols do not support variadic arguments. What's probably happening is that "&" is taken as an argument symbol instead of a variadic indicator / list comprehension.

Comment: You're right. How frustrating! I must be misunderstanding something about the intended use of protocols if that's the case.