# Issue with protocols in Clojure: "No single method: ..." error

Tags: clojure, protocols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do clojure protocols allow one to have a variadic method the way funcions do (with an ampersand)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401378/do-clojure-protocols-allow-one-to-have-a-variadic-method-the-way-funcions-do-wi)

I'm getting this error when running some Clojure code using a protocol:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No single method: add_component of interface: questar.entity.Entity found for function: add-component of protocol: Entity, compiling:(questar/entity.clj:17)
```

Here's the code in question:

```
(defprotocol Entity
  (add-component [this cname & args])
  (update-component [this cname f & args])
  (remove-component [this cname])
  (get-component [this cname])
  (has-component? [this cname]))

(extend-protocol Entity
  clojure.lang.IPersistentMap
    (add-component [this cname & args]
      (assoc entity cname (apply new-component cname args)))
    (update-component [this cname f & args]
      (let [component (get-component this cname)]
        (add-component this cname (apply f component args))))
    (remove-component [this cname]
      (dissoc this cname))
    (get-component [this cname]
      (this cname))
    (has-component? [this cname]
      (contains? this cname))

  clojure.lang.IDeref
    (add-component [this cname & args]
      (alter this (apply add-component cname args)))
    (update-component [this cname f & args]
      (alter this (apply update-component cname f args)))
    (remove-component [this cname]
      (alter this remove-component cname))
    (get-component [this cname]
      (get-component this @cname))
    (has-component? [this cname]
      (has-component? this @cname)))
```

I know this can be related to the arity, but everything looks correct to me. Is this because it can't figure out which version of add-component to call?

Thanks!

Comment: I think amalloy is right, and that question has good answers.

Comment: amalloy: Yes, it's a dup. Do I need to delete this? Chouser: I saw your answer before you deleted it and I appreciated the work-around you offered. Sadly your work-around is not mentioned on the other question.

Comment: @user1103052 No, the way it works is if enough (five) people vote to close the question within some period of time (two days?), then it's automatically closed, and a big ol' header goes at the top redirecting to the other page (I think). So you shouldn't have to do anything about it, though you can if you want.