# How do I break a Scheme list into args to be passed to a procedure?

Tags: scheme, max, list-manipulation, r5rs

I want to use the predefined `(max)` function (R5RS) with a `list` of numbers, which varies in length.  Unfortunately, `(max)` accepts input like this:

```
(max 2 43 5 6)
=> 43
```

I'm attempting to use it like so:

```
(define lst '(3 5 53 4 53 54 32))
(max lst)
```

This produces the following error.

```
max: expects argument of type <real number>; given (3 5 53 4 53 54 32)
```

How can I break this list into the individual arguments I need, as I'm passing them to `(max)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might consider using [`apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257028/why-should-i-use-apply-in-clojure/1257066#1257066) (though be warned, that this may impose limits with respect to the number of elements/arguments are acceptable, depending on your implementation of Scheme):

```
(apply max '(3 4 2 1 78 2 1))
```

In general, if the number of elements is not known to be small, it might be safer to do it manually:

```
(define max* (list)
    (if (null? list) (negative-infinity)
        (let loop ((list (cdr list)) (best (car list)))
            (if (null? list) best (loop (cdr list) (max best (car list)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using apply basically translates into running `(max 3 4 2 1 78 2 1)` but the number of arguments a procedure can be passed is not infinite on some systems.  For `max`, you can take advantage of its commutativity by using fold:

```
(fold-left max -inf.0 '(3 4 2 1 78 2 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a procedure that compares the first item to the second,

```
(define (largestele lst)
        (if (null? (cdr lst))
            (car lst)
            (if (> (car lst) (cadr lst))
                (largestele (cons (car lst) (cddr lst)))
                (largestele (cdr lst)))))
```